# linked list Sorting in alphabetically and frequency order

Tags: java, linked-list, processing-efficiency

I have a linked list project. So I wrote the insert method, getCount(E key){Count of frequency of word inserted(haw many of the words are repeated) },getWords(int n) { gets the first n words in format of (word, count)},iterator().
and my out put is:

(cat,3)(bob,2)(cat,3)(bob,2)(cat,3)(alice,2)(alice,2)

so the project wants the out put to be sorted based on the number of frequency and if the frequency is same, it would sort it in alphabetical order. So the out put should be:

(cat,3)(alice,2)(bob,2)

it also didn't printed the ones that are repeated.
how can I sort them should I changed my insert method or make new method just for sorting?
insert method:

public boolean insert(E key) {

```
     Node curr = first;
     if (first == null || !first.key.equals(key)) {
            first = new Node(key,first);
        
        }else {
           
            while (curr.next != null) {
                   curr = curr.next;
            }
            
            curr.next = new Node(key);

            N++;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: `'java' !== 'javascript'`

Comment: sorry for mistake

Answer (score 0):

Make a new method definitely. Putting it into the frequency method will make it very messy.
I can help you with the code if you want, so tell me if you do.
But I think a usual merge or quicksort will work, with an added condition for equality. I don't think repeated words should be a problem.
Some references ,
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-linked-list/